# How to calculate attendence in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have some data of employees. I want to create an attendence chart of employees.

Data is like this:

```
paycode     date         time
----------------------------------------    
4007        11-02-2013  19:51:00.0000000
4007        11-02-2013  20:00:00.0000000
4007        11-02-2013  20:36:00.0000000
4007        11-02-2013  21:05:00.0000000
4007        11-02-2013  21:55:00.0000000
4007        11-02-2013  22:32:00.0000000
4007        11-02-2013  22:52:00.0000000
4007        11-02-2013  23:22:00.0000000
4007        11-02-2013  23:52:00.0000000
4007        11-03-2013  00:26:00.0000000
4007        11-03-2013  01:05:00.0000000
4007        11-03-2013  01:32:00.0000000
```

I want results to look like this:

```
 paycode  date  intime   outtime working_hour
 ---------------------------------------------
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You should specify exactly what intime, outtime, working_hour mean and provide us with example output.
What have you tried? Do you have any ideas? Or do you expect us to solve the problem for you?

Comment: What does the time column mean? maybe you are missing a checkin and checkout column in your design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
select paycode, date, min(time) as intime, max(time) as outtime, 
((DATEDIFF(MINUTE, min(time), max(time))/60 + 'hr' +  (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, min(time), max(time))%60 + 'min')as working_hour
from tablename 
group by paycode,date
```

Comment: intime and outtime give same time

Comment: @davidsam:- Updated my answer!